# VBA Excel set variable to row number with .row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of files and want to find the areas under portions of the curve.
I define how many curves, the X1 and X2.

The macro then finds the row x1 and x2 and then should give me the row number that they are contained in, but I keep getting an error at this step.

Then later on it uses these values to calcultae the area.

It worked once, I made a change to a variable and have never gotten it to work right since.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim myRange, TotalPeak, TotalBack, FoundCell_1, FoundCell_2, J, FileNumber, Point_1, Point_2, CPoint_1, CPoint_2

FileNumber = InputBox("Number of curves")
Point_1 = InputBox("Enter point one of curve")
Point_2 = InputBox("Enter point two of curve")

For J = 1 To FileNumber

FoundCell_1 = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=Point_1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
FoundCell_2 = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=Point_2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

CPoint_1 = FoundCell_1.Row
CPoint_2 = FoundCell_2.Row

myRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(CPoint_1, J + 1), Cells(CPoint_2, J + 1))
TotalPeak = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange)
TotalBack = ((Cells(CPoint_1, J + 1) + Cells(CPoint_2, J + 1)) / 2) * Abs((CPoint_2 - CPoint_1))
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(J, 1) = TotalPeak - TotalBack

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What change to what variable did you make to make it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Set` the lines below, since they are to be a range variable, and a range is an object.

Change this:

```
FoundCell_1 = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=Point_1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
FoundCell_2 = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=Point_2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

To:

```
Set FoundCell_1 = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=Point_1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
Set FoundCell_2 = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=Point_2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

This change will allow for the `.Row` property to be pulled from your range object.